# Plotting salinity data using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R so please bare with me.

I have a bunch of salinity data which I have sliced down to an approximate region of study and I would like to plot this data on a map using ggplot. I have a 66x164x75 array of salinity data. The third dimension represents different depths, obviously I am fine to show these on separate plots.

So far I have tried this:

```
#Slices to correct region
correct.region <- vosaline[944:1009,160:323,1:75]
#changes to dataframe for ggplot
region.df <- as.data.frame(correct.region)

#map plot
ggplot(data=region.df,aes(x='Latitude',y='Longitude')) + geom_sf()
```

This returns an error of

> Error in `check_required_aesthetics()`:
> ! stat_sf requires the following missing aesthetics: geometry

I appreciate any help.

EDIT:
Based on a suggest by Allan I have now changed my code to slice the latitude longitude data so that they can be used in the gg command. Note that my Latitude/Longitude data is stored as a 66x164x2 array with the first layer being all latitude and second all longitude pairs.

```
#Slices to correct region
correct.region <- vosaline[944:1009,160:323,1]
correct.latlong <- nav_latlong[944:1009,160:323,1:2]
#changes to dataframe for ggplot
region.df <- as.data.frame(correct.region)
latlong.df <- as.data.frame(correct.latlong)

#map plot
ggplot(data=region.df,aes(x=correct.latlong[,,1],y=correct.latlong[,,2],fill=region.df)) + geom_raster()
```

However, this now returns the error

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
> Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
> ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (66): x, y and fill
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Try `ggplot(data=region.df,aes(x=Latitude,y=Longitude, fill = Depth)) + geom_raster()` Note that you don't put quotes around the variable names inside ggplot.  Also note, I don't know what your depth column is called, so you'll need to change that accordingly. You can use `geom_sf` here, which is specifically only for plotting `sf` objects, and doesn't know what to do with ordinary x, y, z data.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I have edited my original question with a further error.

Comment: Your call should be something like: `ggplot(data = region.df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = depth)) + geom_raster()` where `lon`, `lat` and `depth` are columns of dataframe `region.df`